# Dealing with big memory chunks in GO

Tags: memory-management, go

Are there any guidelines which describe how Go may effectively address following use cases :

1. Application receives 100M string consisting of delimited names, each name up to 1M long. E.g.: "Ben;Aaron;Rich;Donna...".  Need to print out the same names in alphabet order without significant memory usage increase (let's say up to 150M RAM used in total)
2. Given two collections with huge memory chunks (let's say up to 1M each) and need to effectively move few chunks from one collection to the other (without significant additional memory allocation)

Comment: Is there a maximum on the number of names? Could there be 50M names of 1 character each?

Comment: @Tomas, let's assume there is no limit - but I am more interested in general concepts - so any suggestions would help

Comment: I strongly suggest attempting a naive implementation, profiling it, and then posting code/results if it doesn't have the performance you need.

Comment: @elithrar seem this is the way to go, I just wanted to ask if there is anything I should know before starting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I assume that you cannot modify the string so the string and the string is immutable (not []byte), because removing any of such limitations makes the task trivial. If so, then you can create additional structure with string indices and sort in it (n*log(n)) time. Just implement `Less` in a way it compares the substrings in original string.
2. The second one is trivial - just use linked list.

Comment: Do you think that indices will not take much memory, especially in Go? And regarding 2. so how exactly the code will look like? dest.PushBack(src.Remove(elem))  ?

Comment: @noonex, the go memory layout is very straightforward, you can see how everything is allocated. Otherwise the algorithms and data structures are the same as in any other language.